# Android Studio cant resolve gradle dependencies

Tags: android, maven, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I've created the below App in android studio. At runtime I receive the below posted errors. I've checked the build.gradle file but I do not know whats 
wrong with it.

The problem is that android studio gives an error at R.layout and says: can't resolve symbol R

**code**:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.act_main);
    }
}
```

**gradle.build**:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.com.bt_11"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 21
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.+'
}
```

**ERROR**.

```
Error:A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
> Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':app:_debugCompile'.
> Could not resolve com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.+.
 Required by:
     BT_11:app:unspecified
  > Could not resolve com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.+.
     > Failed to list versions for com.android.support:appcompat-v7.
        > Unable to load Maven meta-data from https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/maven-metadata.xml.
           > Could not GET 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/maven-metadata.xml'.
              > Connection to https://jcenter.bintray.com refused
```

**update**:
I set compileSdkVersion, targetSdkVersion to 23 and minSdkVersion = 19

and now i am getting the followin errors when tryin to run the App:

- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.

  > Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':app:_debugCompile'.
  >   Could not resolve com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.+.
  >    Required by:
  >        BT_11:app:unspecified
  >   Could not resolve com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.+.
  >   Failed to list versions for com.android.support:appcompat-v7.
  >   Unable to load Maven meta-data from https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/maven-metadata.xml.
  >   Could not GET 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/maven-metadata.xml'.
  >   Connection to https://jcenter.bintray.com refused

Answer (score 0):

First of all **update** your **SDK MANAGER**.
It should resolve the issue that gradle is not able to resolve `com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.+.`

[image]

Then in your build.gradle you have to change your `compileSdkVersion`.
The appcompat v23 **requires**  `compileSdkVersion 23`

Comment: should i change the targetSdkVersion as well to be V23ß thank you and appreciate your help..because i tried to change it, and i tried only to change the targetSdkVersion but i still face the same error

Comment: would you please have alook at the update section above

Comment: You have the same issue. Check your SDK Manager (see the updated answer). About targetSdk you don't need to use 23.

Comment: thanks again, actually i check the SDK and it is already updated, and followed what you suggested, but unfortunately i still have the same problem...and i found out that the "Theme." in style.xml file cant be recognised as well..so i posted another question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32721761/can-not-running-app-on-android-studio  and it could be yours :)