# Can not running App on android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-manifest, android-theme

when i create a new project in android studio i find the the activity class initially extends AppCompatActivity and i have to change it to extend
Activity instead.

but the issue that i am facing is, R class is not recognisable and i receive the error "Cant resolve symbol R". i posted the build.gradle
file below and it seems to me it has no errors.

also, after tryin to find out the solution, i checked all the xml files and i found that the style.xml "posted below" has error at "Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar"
and android studio cant resolve it.

please let me know how to fix this error.

**code**:
    public class MainActivity extends Activity {

```
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.xxx.xxx);//cant resolve symbol R
    }
}
```

**style.xml**:

```
    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">//cant resolve symbol Theme+cant resolve symbol AppCompat
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    </style>

</resources>
```

**gradle.build**:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.com.bt_11"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 21
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.+'
}
```

Comment: change your compilesdkversion to 21 from 23

Answer (score 1):

You will have to change the theme to Holo Light or Holo Dark or Material theme as pasted below;

```
<resources>

    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    </style>

</resources>
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, but i have a question, should i modify the build.gradle file?

Comment: No need! Please up vote if this response answers your query.